# Publish SharePoint app with ScriptLink UserCustomAction to Office Store

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-store

I want to create an App that registers a custom script link at each page of the SharePoint website.

Is there a way to achieve this in such way that the app does not need full control permission?

We have implemented this by creating a `UserCustomAction` with `location="ScriptLink"` but it requires Full Controll permissions. And as we know, [Apps that request full-control permissions are not accepted in the Office Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220035.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Do not execute the code from your App installer.

Let the code be executed by the installed App,
that will run the code with the users rights, so requires a Site Collection admin by preference

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Can you add more details, please? Currently the code is added on the App Web page. So user goes to App Web and then clicks our Install button that run our installation code.

Comment: This is an interesting thought, but how to do it? All App code in app web runs in context of App+User rights. With manage permissions we can't even create an .aspx file in host web.

Comment: Yes, if you can not get into the house you can not move the furniture. So you need someone accepted into the house first who lets you [in](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51eyNwb0mmL.jpg). An easier  non-Addin approach is to let users execute a [Bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) But with at least write access Add-ins can add JavaScript into some [weird](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How) SharePoint locations.